# highcharts-vue dynamically change colorAxis from scalar to classed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have a highcharts-vue component that draws a world map and several indicators (datasets, changed by a dropdown) which change the color of countries. I need to be able to change the legend drawn by the `colorAxis` from scalar(gradient) type to classed type dynamically depending on the indicator.

Recent attempt is to set `mapOptions` config for `highcharts` in `computed` and onChange event handler change `this.colorAxis` based on the indicator `id`. My problem is, if I start with a scalar based axis like the example below, it will change to a classed axis with its corresponding `id` but when I try to switch it back to a scalar based, it won't work.

For example:

```
// default colorAxis
colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      minColor: 'yellow',
      maxColor: 'blue',
      startOnTick: false,
      endOnTick: false,
      minorTickInterval: 1.5,
    }

// onchange in methods   
changeHandler: function() {
      if (this.id === 1) {
        this.colorAxis = {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          minColor: 'yellow',
          maxColor: 'blue',
          startOnTick: false,
          endOnTick: false,
          minorTickInterval: 1.5,
        }
      } else {
        this.colorAxis = {
        dataClassColor: 'category',
        dataClasses: [
          {
            from: 1,
            to: 20,
            color: '#FFF45A',
          },
          {
            from: 20,
            to: 40,
            color: '#FFB743',
          }, 
          {
            from: 40,
            to: 60,
            color: '#FF684D',
          }
         ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use and edit this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj. Try to simplify the code and use sample data so that the demo presents only the main problem.

Comment: Here it is :) 
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-osvlb?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Comment: You have to set `colorAxis.dataClasses = false` when coming back to default settings. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-g6o19